# How to deploy NodeJS multi module/package project? (frontend & backend)

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, multi-module

I tried to create a multi module/package project with npm today.

The structure is as following:

`root
|
|____ backend <-- npm package containing all routes
|
|____ frontend <-- npm package containing all js/html/css files
|
|____ dist <-- merged output from backend & frontend
|
|____ build_and_run.sh <-- shell script to invoke npm in both - frontend and backend and run the final application in "dist/"`

The frontend should be in the "dist/static" directory.
Both - the frontend and backend are using different dependencies and compiling steps (TypeScript, VueJS etc.), so the differentiation between frontend and backend currently makes the most sense to me.

My problem is the deploying of both modules/packages into the final directory.
Copying the files isn't a problem, but deploying dependencies into the "dist" directory is (e.g. express).

The second goal is to create a Docker file, but this option shouldn't be neccessary for running the server.

If someone has a better structure or solution fitting my needs, I would definitely appreciate to hear it.

Comment: do you any link to GitHub or sample app so this will easy to dockerized some existing thing instead of something in your thoughts

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/Microsamp/Ninja

Comment: dist <-- merged output from backend & frontend ... How you did this step in your local machine without docker?

Comment: Actually tried to write a little script (build_and_run.sh/build.sh), but I haven't yet realized how to "export" the dependencies (are all files in node_modules actually needed in production?). 
Btw: I'm currently using a seperate branch for testing purposes.

Sometimes I feel like I'm just thinking like a Java Dev (Maven, shading, class loaders etc) - not like a Web Dev and that's the main problem ^^'